# TBitmap.Create not working in delphi console application

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I need to process a set of  bmp files using a console application, i'm using the TBitmap class, but the code doesn't compile because this error

```
E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Create'
```

This sample app reproduces the issue

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
 System.SysUtils,
 Vcl.Graphics,
 WinApi.Windows;

procedure CreateBitMap;
Var
  Bmp  : TBitmap;
  Flag : DWORD;
begin
  Bmp:=TBitmap.Create; //this line produce the error of compilation
  try
    //do something
  finally
   Bmp.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    CreateBitMap;

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

why this code doesn't compile?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The issue is in the order of your uses clause, the WinApi.Windows and Vcl.Graphics units have a type called TBitmap, when the compiler find an *ambiguous*  type  resolves the type using the last unit of the uses list where is present. in this case use the TBitmap of the Windows unit which points to the [BITMAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinAPi structure , to resolve this change the order of your units to

```
uses
 System.SysUtils,
 WinApi.Windows,
 Vcl.Graphics;
```

or you can declare the type using the full qualified name like so

```
procedure CreateBitMap;
Var
  Bmp  : Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap;
  Flag : DWORD;
begin
  Bmp:=Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap.Create;
  try
    //do something
  finally
   Bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```